# Using Swift in project with Objective C static library target

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm currently working on a project which mainly consists of an objective-c static library compiled into a framework using a shell build script.

I want to add new features to the project which would be written in swift.
Since swift can't be compiled into a static library, I've thought of adding a framework target which would be linked with the objective-c library.

In addition, the swift code has to be able to use objective-c code from the static library and vice-versa .

What can I do considering the aforementioned requirements?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add swift coding to objective c project or vice-versa try bridging concept